# when to use oop in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Concern about oops. I have following example taken from internet. In that example they create instance of car class and then they alert.

```
function Car(speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

var car1 = new Car(40);
var car2 = new Car(60);

alert("Car1 Speed: " + car1.speed);
alert("Car2 Speed: " + car2.speed);
```

My question is, We can achive the same result with oops concept from the following concept so why use oops and in what condition we really need oops.

```
function Car(speed) {
    return speed;
}

alert("Car1 Speed: " + Car(40));
alert("Car2 Speed: " + Car(60));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a lot of cases where you would use something like the first, and a lot of cases where you would use something like the second, and a lot of cases that could go either way.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a car as a method for returning speed.
What happens when you have multiple properties? Will you create a function per property?
What happens when you inherit Car (Speed Car)? 
What happens when you want to add functionality to all Cars?

```
function Car(speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

// all cars will have this function
Car.prototype.GetSpeed = function()
    return this.speed;
}

var c = new Car(30);
console.log(c.GetSpeed());
```

Comment: This just examplifies that the question is too broad without giving any answers... You can't teach a coding paradigm in a single answer. I wonder who the two people who found it useful are..

Comment: I agree that you cant teach coding in a single answer but you can give some examples and show a couple of best practices..

Comment: Yet you do neither, the naming is inconsistent with the canonical naming scheme of JS. You don't explain why it's beneficial to do this, or why one should/shouldn't - which is quite natural since it's too broad for a single answer. All this will do will provide future visitors with more confusion.

Comment: Not to mention that the actual example itself is pretty stupid, since all it exemplifies is that wrapping things in classes adds code cruft over numbers.

Comment: I did explain the benefits of doing that. What he did will work for one property and not on all "Cars". What he did was basically used Car as a function and not as a object. I'm not going to argue with you. If you think the answer is bad then just down vote it..

Comment: There is no point in downvoting it since the question will very likely be deleted anyway as it's way too broad. I was trying to use its remaining lifetime to try to convince you not to leave such answers , especially since you seem to _do_ have a bunch of answers that _are_ rather good.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm completely missing the point, but in the first option, you're creating an "object".
so, you have a `Car`, which has a variable, `speed`.
you can the add more variables (properties/members) to that class, for example, the numbers of wheels, or what not, and they are all enclosed in that `Car` concept.

In your second part, you simply have a function that shows what you give it ... 
you can go a step furter and just do:

```
alert("Car1 Speed: 40");
```

It depends on what you need and or trying to achieve ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The first case would allow you to hold/save the speed of a car on an object. Independently of all other car objects. You could then call, change, and use in another function.

The second case would return the value and the be lost in the functions scope upon returning.